# Write InvalidOperationException System.InvalidOperationException: The port is closed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, serial-port

I have been writing data into serial port communication. When writing to the Port that's opened and working fine for few hours, then suddenly there's exception saying the port is closed, this happened not all the time, it's intermittent. 
What usually can be the caused of this ? 
Physical serial port connection ? 
or the hardware that is trying to communicate to is faulty ? or what ?

**UPDATED**

```
try
{
    Port.Write(buffer, 0, (int)buffer[1]);

}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{

    log("Write InvalidOperationException " + util.ByteArray2Str(buffer, 50), LogType.Error);
    log(ex.ToString(), LogType.Error);

    //Exception
    //Write InvalidOperationException 
    //System.InvalidOperationException: The port is closed.
}
```

Comment: Chances are that the port is being closed after a period of inactivity. Probably by the hardware that is being communicated with. Just check the connection and reconnect is necessary.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane Thanks, I have check between the last communication with the time when this exception happend is only 2-3 minutes. So I think inactivity won't be the issue for this case. Is there's such a thing as too much and too fast the data is being written to the hardware and so it can't cope, then it's exception as port closed ?

Comment: Does the issue always occur round the same timeframe? i.e. Has the connection been opened for the same amount of time when it's suddenly closed? Also I'd check the timeout on both your port settings and those of the hardware you're communicating with.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane It's at different timeframe, some of them 30 minutes inactivity then there's a port closed issue. So do you think if I increase the port write timeout setting, this will help to reduce the port closed issue ? But if it's timeout, isn't that it should report exception of "write timeout" rather than port closed ? What can I check about the hardware ? Can the damage of physical com port cause this issue ? or com port too loose ?

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in try-catch? That should give you more info on what exactly the error is.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I have updated the code. As stated in my question the exception is "Port is Closed", but intermittent.